# Deserialize object using function in Jackson json

Tags: java, json, function, jackson, deserialization

I have a function that produces an object. Would it be possible to deserialize this object using Jackson JSON annotations?

```
class Foo{
  Bar getBar(int par1, int par 2){
    ...
  }
  public static void main( String[] args )  {
    String json = "{\"par1\":1,\"par2\":2}";
    Bar bar = new ObjectMapper().<invoke function getBar>.readValue(json);
  }
}
```

Comment: i think the json format is invalid. You are missing `{}` . Try: `"{\"par1\":1,\"par2\":2}"`

Comment: Oops, yes, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Jackson to use a factory method or non default constructor using the `@JsonCreator` annotation.  However, the method has to be part of the Class that is deserialized.  So, assuming `Bar` has a two args constructor:

```
public class Bar {
  @JsonCreator
  public Bar (@JsonProperty("par1") int par1, @JsonProperty("par2") int par 2) {
    ...
  }
  public static void main( String[] args )  {
    String json = "{\"par1\":1,\"par2\":2}";
    Bar bar = (Bar)new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Bar.class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that is parsing this Json String to Jacksons `JsonNode`, and then invoke your method.

Something like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args )  {
    String json = "{\"par1\":1,\"par2\":2}";
    JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
    Bar bar = Foo.getBar(jsonNode.get("par1").asInt(), jsonNode.get("par2").asInt());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible solutiun is to add par1 and par2 to your Foo class. But don't forget to add @JSONIgnore to "get" methods which aren't usefull for json parsing.

```
class Foo{
  int par1;
  int par2;

  @JsonIgnore
  Bar getBar(){
     //..par1 par2 logic;
  }
  int getPar1(){
     return par1;
  }
  void setPar1(int par1) {
     this.par1=par1;
  }
  //same setter\getter for par2
}
```

And then you can simply parse JSON to this object and call Bar method

```
String json = "{\"par1\":1,\"par2\":2}";
Bar bar = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json,Foo.class).getBar();
```